# How to change Bootstrap 4's border-bottom-width via SASS?

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

I'm just getting into both Laravel and SASS and I took the opportunity to rewrite my old html template into something re-usable and SASS the CSS rules.

In my HTML template, I had the borders such as follows:

```css
input[type="text"]{
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:red;
  border-width:1px 1px 4px 1px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

So I would have a border-bottom of 4px and rest would be 1px, in the same style and same color. I wanted to override Bootstrap 4's `$border-width` property so I went ahead and changed it to `1px 1px 4px 1px`, and boom. It didn't work.

After inspecting the SASS files, I've noticed that they're not used the way I thought they'd be, but instead they look something like:
`border: $border-width solid $border-color`

So that got me thinking, there are probably several ways to resolve this, one way I went ahead and done so far is:

```
$border-widths:1px 1px 4px 1px;
input[type="text"].form-control{
  border-width:$border-widths!important;
}
```

So I'm leaving the default `$border-width` variable as is, and instead creating my own variable and then selecting the input and overriding the `border-width` property only. Which looks, not right because:

1. This is my _variables.scss override file and I kind of want it to stay that way.
2. I could do this with just CSS override the same way, but then it'd defeat the whole purpose.
3. I have to explicitly use `!important` otherwise I can't override Bootstrap 4's rules.

So, there must be another way, I guess. But what exactly?

Comment: another way without using important?, you need to create a css rule with more weight than Bootstrap css rules, like more specific in order to overwrite them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up simply keeping the `!important` for overriding and just made myself another scss file, and written the rules there:

**_variables.scss**

```
$border-widths:             1px 1px 4px 1px;
```

**_custom.scss**

```
.border-thick-bottom{ border-width:$border-widths!important; border-style:solid; }
```